# How to set Responsive Design for 1600x900 resolution and other resolutions?

Tags: html, css

Okay,I designed my webpage to my liking. Finally. But of course, I designed it on a Chromebook with a 1366x768 resolution. So when I looked on my 1600x900 resolution computer, everything is jacked up. How do I use responsive design to get my webpage to look the same on a 1600x900 resolution as it does on a 1366x768? That's just an example. I would eventually like to format my website for mobile phones, but right now, I am focusing on laptop and desktop resolutions. Any help is appreciated, I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you add your code ..that gives more insight of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a framework, such as Bootstrap, then you would have to use CSS's media queries which would allow you to use specific CSS properties depending on the size of the screen of your output device. You can read a clear explanation, at the Mozilla Developer Network, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). 
Learning to use them it's not a bad idea, but the most popular means to implement responsive design is using Twitter Bootstrap. Of course you would have to read a lot, but there are a lot of tutorials on how to use the framework and once you are familiar with the grid system and some of it's classes you can make your site responsive quite easily.
The official Bootstrap site and documentation can be found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/).
Personally I would suggest you to use Bootstrap since it offers so much functionality without having to make everything from the ground.

Answer (score 0):

This Link may be useful for what you are looking for. 
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/06/bootstrap-add-xl-grid-size-option/
You may use this technique for your need